# Global Action Icon not showing in popover panel header

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bug, global-actions

I've a Global Lightning Component Action and put into Global Publisher Layout. It opens in panel like standard quick actions such as `New Task` or `Log a Call` do, but the custom `Global Action` does not show any icon.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Tried with Custom `Static Resource` Icon as well. The Icon does not come through. Is there a trick to get the Icon and Background color change for `Custom Global Actions` somehow?

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue. Seems like someone just overlooked it.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be like this for ages now. Hard to believe no one has seen it, or just casually over looked it in Salesforce :-)

Comment: Back here 3 years later, and it's still an issue!

Comment: Back again a couple years later, and still an issue. So damn annoying!

Comment: Back again and no change; ugh.

Comment: Please find the newly created bug for this issue. 
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000033KMvQAM

Comment: If u can add this as answer, I can accept it there.